# Android SDK newb install question

Tags: android, installation

I've done my best to do this on my own, but I think is time for help. I downloaded the SDK for offline installation. I got the following components:

- Android SDK tools r3
- Android SDK r8
- Android Platform 2.2

I installed the SDK, copied the tools into the platform-tools folder, and the SDK just won't work. I tried running a sample, it didn't work and even tried running a new avd and it stays with a black screen.

Any help would be very appretiated
Thanks

**UPDATE**

Thanks for your help, the emulator is already starting but Eclipse does not recognizes the installation, it gives an error:

Could not find C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\adb.exe!

I looked for the file and seems is not there, but I used a regular install using the installer_r08-windows.exe file! Is there anything wrong here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator might take quite a while to load when running for the first time.

Comment: is not that, because I let it run for over 3 minutes and didn't do a thing, I have a rather fast PC, it shouldn't take that long...

Comment: maybe you can reproduce some of the steps you took, or post some error messages for further insight

Comment: OK, it did started... problem is I was doing too many things at the same time...  :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Well,If you are running for the first time it will take time to boot up !